# Why scalar parameter value injection doesn't work in constructor?

Tags: php, php-di

I have the settings class:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App;

class Settings
{
    private $settings_dir;
    private $settings_file_name;

//..


    public function __construct(string $dir, string $file_name)
    {
        $this->settings_dir = $dir;
        $this->settings_file_name = $file_name;
        //...
    }
//...
}
```

And config for PHP-DI:

```
<?php
return [
   //...
    \App\Settings::class => DI\autowire()
        ->constructorParameter('dir', __DIR__),
    \App\Settings::class => DI\autowire()
        ->constructorParameter('file_name', 'app.php'),
 //...
];
```

When I launch my app, it says:

> DI\Definition\Exception\InvalidDefinition: Entry "App\Kernel" cannot
>   be resolved: Entry "App\Settings" cannot be resolved: Parameter $dir
>   of __construct() has no value defined or guessable

When I set all the values with one method, it works ok:

```
<?php
return [
   //...
    \App\Settings::class => DI\autowire()
        ->constructor(__DIR__, 'app.php')
];
```

What's wrong? I didn't make any additional DI configuration.

PHP-DI v6.0.2, PHP 7.2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just because of array key duplication. I have to use:

```
\App\Settings::class => DI\autowire()->constructorParameter('dir', __DIR__)->constructorParameter('file_name', 'app.php')
```